# Parameter with that position [2] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist

Tags: sql, spring, db2, xquery, spring-data-jpa

I have below method in Spring Repository while executing the exception is "Parameter with that position [2] did not exist". I tried different options to escape single quote('), hope the problem is with this only. Please suggest.

```
@Query(value="select cus_acc_grp_i,"
            + " xmlquery ('$APP_CMP_WRK_XML/Root/CCPABusRuleAscList/CCPABusRuleAsc[position() >= (?2) and not(position() > (?3)) ]')"
            + " from ADM_APP_CMP_WRK  where CUS_ACC_GRP_I = (?1)", nativeQuery=true)
    AdministrationApplicationCompletion findCurrentPageRulesByClient(@Param("clientId") Integer customerAccountGroupId, 
            @Param("startIndex") Integer startIndex,
            @Param("endIndex") Integer endIndex);
```

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with XQuery under DB2, but it seems you're referring two the second and third parameter while only having two of them registered.

Answer (score 0):

@Smitha

How about you try the below:

```
@Query(value="select cus_acc_grp_i,"
            + " xmlquery ('$APP_CMP_WRK_XML/Root/CCPABusRuleAscList/CCPABusRuleAsc[position() >= (:startIndex) and not(position() > (:endIndex)) ]')"
            + " from ADM_APP_CMP_WRK  where CUS_ACC_GRP_I = (:customerAccountGroupId)", nativeQuery=true)
    AdministrationApplicationCompletion findCurrentPageRulesByClient(@Param("clientId") Integer customerAccountGroupId, 
            @Param("startIndex") Integer startIndex,
        @Param("endIndex") Integer endIndex);
```

Pl let me know if this works :)

Comment: Same error; Parameter with that name [startIndex] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [startIndex] did not exist

Comment: Can u try running the query in db2 with hard-coded values? Just to check if the query runs fine

Comment: If it does run correctly, then I would request you to follow up on @Jens Erat suggestion

Answer (score 0):

We cant define parameters in XMLquery scalar function directly, have to use PASSING within xmlquery to pass parameters. Below is the solution.

SELECT XMLQUERY('//item[productName=$n]'
                  PASSING PO.POrder,
                  CAST(@hv AS INTEGER) AS "n") AS "Result"
     FROM PurchaseOrders PO;